# A css to adjust an element's position

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a lightbox to display something. The lightbox works fine by a several lines HTML code and CSS.
Within the lightbox, there is a "Close the Window" link. I want to click it then close the form. It is expected on the bottom of the form, but it is not now.

I think that it is a CSS style problem. The demo is at [jsfiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/zhshqzyc/HjCyA/4/)

```
 <a id="show-panel" href="#">Show</a>
        <div id="lightbox-panel">
          <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>Goal: </p>
                <br />
          <span>
          <ul style="float:left"><li>Goal 1</li><li>Goal 2</li><li>Goal 3</li></ul>
                </span>

          <p style="float:left" align="center"> <a id="close-panel" href="#">Close this window</a> </p>
        </div>
        <!-- /lightbox-panel -->
        <div id="lightbox"></div>
        <!-- /lightbox -->
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can I suggest that you add clicking the black space as a close window condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using floats the wrong way, is this what you're looking for ?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HjCyA/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the  `float:left` from your `ul` and `p` tags

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HjCyA/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to your CSS:

```
#close-panel {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```